# Why it is unsafe to use continue statament?

Tags: php

Can any one tell why it is not preferable to use **continue;** statement in php coding?

Comment: Huh? Who is saying that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I dont see a "real" reason not to use it, but I can imagine, that loops can get a little bit confusing, if they are big and complex. Imagine if you see such a loop and dont realize the *continue*-keyword. Now you would expect, that the loop will get executed to the end every iteration. Especially if you use *continue* with the optional argument this can get really awkward.

Comment: This is probably what the OP's source was referring to. +1

Comment: sounds like the same reason why `return` might be considered harmful... multiple exits.

Comment: Yes, right: It is the same reason, and also it is for *break*.

Answer (score 4):

I am not aware of any general reason not to use `continue`. It is a perfectly fine language construct.

If you have a source saying `continue` is bad, please add it to your question for discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Some see `break` and `continue` as a "`goto` in disguise". Using these language constructs are perfectly valid. If you don't feel comfortable using them, don't.